# How can I further code my merged_sort method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

So this one is really tough since it uses recursion and I cant go anymore further than this. I dont know what to do next. 
for description, merge_sort divides the array until it has been divided into single elements and then I dont know what to do next its really hard I have been thinking this through since 8 hours

```
def merge_sort ( array )

  return if array.length < 2 

  a = merge_sort(array.slice!(0..array.length/2))
  b = merge_sort(array)

end 

def merge ( a , b )
  merged = []
  j_a = 0 # pointer to the first list
  k_b = 0 # pointer to the second list

  while j_a < a.length || k_b < b.length 
    if a[j_a] > b[k_b] 
      merged << b[k_b]
      k_b += 1
    else 
      merged << a[j_a]
      j_a += 1
    end 

    if j_a == a.length # pointer has reached the end of first list? append the whole of 2nd `list`
      merged << b[k_b..-1] 
    else 
      merged << a[j_a..-1] # else append the first list to merged.
    end 
  end
  merged 
end
```

Comment: It may be that everyone on the planet but me knows what “merge-sort” means, but I doubt it. You are asking us to figure out what you are trying to do by studying your code. That’s ineffective and a waste of our time. You need to edit your question, beginning by explaining what you wish to achieve, providing at least one example that includes the desired return value. “...merge_sort divides the array until it has been divided into single elements .” is insufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well I ended up finally writing a fully functional merge_sort function thanks to pry-byebug. At that  time I couldnt process it so I had to put it on stackover flow for someone to tell me whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort has two phases, (1) divide, and (2) conquer/merge.
The divide phase splits an array into left and right halves.
The merge phase merges the results.
Your merge_sort() function needs to be called recursively on the left half and the right half, each returning a sorted subarray.
Then the merge function needs to be called to merge the two subarrays.

Basically, when you want to sort an array, the recursive function divides array in half during recursion, then merge sorted halves as recursion unwinds, something like this,

```
# merge sort array charles
def merge_sort ( charles )
    return if charles.length < 2
    k = charles.length
    L = merge_sort(charles[0:k/2])
    R = merge_sort(charles[k/2+1:k])
    # missing merge
    return merge(L,R)
end
```

Comment: I still cant figure it out :(